# event.preventDefault does not seem to work....why?

Tags: jquery

Working in local, so I cannot give you any link but I will try to explain the situation.

I'm doing a wordpress website and I'm creating ajax requests to make any internal link on the site will load into the main content area of the main page.

Here is the entire script that I'm using

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //individua il container in cui sarà caricata la pagina
    var $mainContent = $("#main-wrapper"),
        //individua l'url "madre"
        siteUrl = "http://" + top.location.host.toString(),
        url = '';

    $(document).on("a[href^='"+siteUrl+"']:not([href*=/wp-admin/]):not([href*=/wp-login.php]):not([href$=/feed/])", "click", function(event) {
        location.hash = this.pathname;
        if ( event.preventDefault ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
        url = window.location.hash.substring(1); 
        if (!url) {
            return;
        } 
        url = url + " #content"; 
        $mainContent.animate({opacity: "0.1"}).html('&lt;p&gt;Please wait...&lt;/&gt;').load(url, function() {
            $mainContent.animate({opacity: "1"});
        });
    });

     $(window).trigger('hashchange');
})
```

In a few words, you can see how I'm trying to "disable" the link: I want to avoid the loading of the link to the external page

The error that I receive in the console is this:

> event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard
>   event.preventDefault() instead.

How can I fix it?

Comment: just use `event.preventDefault();` it is normalized

Comment: @A.Wolff mmmmhhh, but the loading of the page is not prevented: it happens. I guess there is an error...

Comment: @marco ya, you are using delegate() syntax here which is wrong, see jayarjo's answer

Answer (score 5):

I believe event type should come first in your `on` binding and then the selector:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[...])", function(event) ...
```

Comment: yes! right! and then, i catch also an error in ":not([href*=/wp-admin/]):not([href*=/wp-login.php]):not([href$=/feed/])" (i don't know what is this error but it does not matter, for now I just want to see the effects of my ajax functions). It works. thanks!